# Print singly linked list segmentation fault

Tags: c

Can someone explain why I get segmentation fault: 11 when calling display_list(head) in the main function?

I don't get the segmentation fault when I initialize the list (head) with NULL, but I don't understand why this is needed or if it is the best practice in this situation. Sorry for the messy code, I am new to C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#define NEWLINE printf("\n");

struct element {
    int value;
    struct element * next;
};

typedef struct element listelement; 
typedef listelement * list; 

void display_list(list l) {
    if (l == NULL) printf("leer\n");
    else
    {
            while (l != NULL) {
                printf("%d ", l->value);
                l = l->next;
            }
            NEWLINE;
    }
}

int main() {

    display_list(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Even though your question is answered, please don't edit away the question. The answers don't make sense without it, and they might help someone else in future.

Comment: @raydex you must not make edits to answers if you aren't improving the answer. Deleting everything and saying that it is the wrong answer to a question is not good and will always be rejected. Up and downvoting is the mechanism for the community to decide on the value of an answer. If you want to communicate with the author of the answer: use the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The display_list function relies on having a null pointer in the `next` member of a listelement to detect when it gets to the end of the list.

```
            while (l != NULL) {
                printf("%d ", l->value);
                l = l->next;
            }
```

When you initialize `head` to NULL and add the first element to the list, that null value of `head` gets stored in the first element's `next` member, which properly terminates the list in the way that the display_list function expects.  When you don't initialize `head` to NULL, the `next` pointer of that first element contains garbage and you get a segmentation fault when the display_list function tries to follow the garbage pointer to the next element.

Answer (score 2):

In your `insert` function, you don't need to pass `list *l` as it is already a pointer.
Also, your `insert` is function is not changing the value of your `head` variable.

You can try doing something like this:

```c
// return new head element
list insert(int v, listelement* l) {
    listelement * new; 
    new = malloc(sizeof(listelement)); 
    new->value = v; 
    new->next = l;
    return new;
}

// then in main do insert values as
int main() {
    list head;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        head = insert(i, head);
    }
    display_list(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  Memory access error: dereferencing an uninitialized pointer; abort execution.
  # Reading 4 bytes from a random address (0x8199f38).
  #
  # Stack trace (most recent call first) of the read.
  # [0]  file:/prog.c::35, 17
  # [1]  file:/prog.c::54, 5
  # [2]  [libc-start-main]
```

Here is the [link](https://cee.studio/?bucket=200604-Qpk&name=Mj7Ta) to debug this segfault.  Just click "Run".